# Bootstrap Dialog Global options?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have many dialog popups spread across many pages, each utilizing BoostrapDialog

```
BootstrapDialog.show({...});
or 
var x = new BootstrapDialog({...});
```

I want to add the "closeByBackdrop: true" option to all of them.
Is there a way to define some default options? I'm thinking along the same lines as jQuery's ajaxSettings() where you can set global options (but still override them in each specific instance if necessary)

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false,
    error: function(x, t, m){
        alert("Generic Error");
    }
});
```

I cant't find any information remotely related to a global options setter anywhere...which leads me to think there is no such thing. wondering if someone knows of this... or even better has implemented their own way of achieving this.

The obvious solution is to manually go through all my dialogs and add the option manually, but since **this is the preferred way they should ALL work**, i'd like to not have to specify it for every instance.

The other solution would be to re code them all to accept my own options object, and just extend that object for each instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    modalOptions = {...};
});    

function openDialogX(){

    var dialogXOptions = modalOptions;
    dialogXOptions.buttons = [...];
    dialogXOptions.title = "...";
    dialogXOptions.message = "...";

    var dialogX = new BootstrapDialog(dialogXOptions);
}
```

**It would be nice to not have to re-code them all to accept a custom options object.**

**TL;DR:**
Is there a BoostrapDialog equivalent to jQuery's ajaxSettup() for redefining default options. If not, what solutions have you used to achieve this (if at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do* have a `BootstrapDialog.defaultOptions` around [**line 231 in the master repo**](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-dialog.js#L231). Use that to modify the defaults to whatever you need :

```js
$.extend( BootstrapDialog.defaultOptions, {
  closable: true,
  closeByBackdrop: true,
  autodestroy: false
} );
```

and take benefit of the new settings in all dialogs :

```js
var myDialog = new BootstrapDialog({
  title: 'Example',
  message: 'Sample text'
}).open()
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ffj6r1b6/** (try change `closeByBackdrop` to `false` and re-run)

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks. P.s. **Why isn't this documented?** Now i know what i'm looking for i get valid google results...well 1 result in an unrelated question.

Comment: Hey @Steve, sry for the long delay, thank you for accepting the answer! I dont know why it is not documented, but it is very common for such plugins that hey have a `.defaultOptions` or `.defaults` of some kind, All bootstrap plugins have them as well. You could go "higher" up, and force all bootstrap modals to have some different `.defaults` - just look for it in the source, and do as above.

Comment: dont know if it's worth asking here, or creating a new question...using the above method, is it possible to extend the default BootstrapDialog buttons options - but without extending the whole BootstrapDialog interface to a custom one? (I'm wanting to add data-toggle but currently having to give the button Id's and then in "onShown", add the data-toggle)